# Pointers - reading, writing, copying text in c in two files

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, io

I have a task. I must write a program which gets a text from a file (source.txt) and put them into the array, then I write this array into another file(result.txt), then I copy array to another array and put this array into result.txt and then I take chars from a keyboard and put them into the array and into txt file. I must create functions in separately files and I must work on **POINTERS**. 
The compilation of my program is ok, but in result.txt I have nothing and I don't know why?
This is my main program eng.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "eng_fun.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c, i; 
    char *s, *t, *r;  
    FILE *wz, *wc;                         
    char arr[10000];
    s = arr;
    char copyArr[10000];    
    t = copyArr;
    char keyArr[10000]; 
    r = keyArr;

    if (argc != 3) {                              
    printf("Wrong arguments number\n");
    printf("I should run this way:\n");
    printf("%s source result\n",argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }

    if( (wz= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if( (wc= fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Open error %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(2);
    }

    fprintf(wc, "Read text from file source.txt and write into result.txt:\n");

    readText(wz, s, 10000);   
    writeText(wc, s); 
    textStats(wc, s);

    fprintf(wc, "\nCopy and paste array and write into result.txt:\n\n");

    copyText(s, t, 10000);        
    writeText(wc, t);                   
    textStats(wc, t);

    fprintf(wc, "\nText from keyboard to array and then to file result.txt\n\n");
    printf("Write some sentence and press CTRL+D. All text will write to result.txt\n");
    while( (*r++ = getchar()) != EOF )

    writeText(wc, r);
    textStats(wc, r);

    int fclose(FILE *wz);
    int fclose(FILE *wc);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my program with functions eng_fun.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int _strlen (char *array)   // here I check array length
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; ++i);    
    return i;   
}

int writeText(FILE *wp, char *s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while((*s++ = fputc(*s, wp)))
    {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;   //I must return array length in my task, so I choose sum to  count how many signs I put
}


int readText(FILE *wp, char *s, int max)
{
    int sum = 0;

    while((*s++ = fgetc(wp)) != EOF)
    {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;  //I must return array length
}

int copyText (char *s, char *t, int max)  
{
    if (_strlen(t) > max)
    {
        printf("This array is too big.");
    }
    else
    {
        while((*s++ = *t++));
    }
    return _strlen(t);  //I must return array length in my task
}

int allSigns(char *s) // count all signs
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
    {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int notWhiteSigns(char *s) //count notWhiteSigns
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
    {
        if ((*s != ' ') && (*s != '\n') && (*s != '\t')  && (*s != '\v'))
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int lines(char *s) // count lines
{
    int sumLines = 1;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
    {
        if (*s++ == '\n')
            sumLines++;
    }
    return sumLines;
}

int words(char *s) // here I count words
{
    int sum = 0;
    *s++;
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        if (*s == ' ' && *(s-1) != ' ' && *s != ('\n' || '\t' || '\v') && (*(s-1) != ('\n' || '\t' || '\v')))
            sum++;
    }
    if (*s-1 != ' ');
        sum++;
    return sum;
}


int textStats(FILE *wp, char *s) // (here I write stats)   
{
    fprintf(wp, "All signs: %i\n not white signs: %i\n words: %i\n lines: %i\n\n\n\n", allSigns(s), notWhiteSigns(s), words(s), lines(s));
    return 0;
}
```

and eng_fun.h file

```
#ifndef A_A
#define A_A

int _strlen (char *tab);
int writeText(FILE *wp, char *s);
int readText(FILE *wp, char *s, int max);
int copyText(char *s, char *t, int max);
int allSigns(char *s);
int notWhiteSigns(char *s);
int lines(char *s);
int words(char *s);
int textStats(FILE *wp, char *s);
#endif
```

My source.txt

```
A computer is a machine that can be instructed to carry out sequences of arithmetic or logical operations 
automatically via computer programming. Modern computers have the ability to follow generalized sets of 
operations, called programs. These programs enable computers to perform an extremely wide range of tasks.
```

And file result.txt in the beginning is empty

I compile my file in that way

```
gcc -c eng.c
gcc -c fun_eng.c
gcc -o eng.x eng.o fun_eng.o
./eng.x source.txt result.txt
```

Compilation is ok, but I have nothing in result.txt

Comment: What is output at the terminal?  Why are you checking argc against 3 for 2 arguments?

Comment: there is 3 arguments ./eng.x (first argument) source.txt(second argument) result.txt(third argument) 
The output of the terminal -> output should be in the result.txt - in this file I write all arrays.